Displaying the sed command before its execution in a Bash script
I need advice on how to make every command I run in a Bash script first display itself and then execute. I created a simple function and a subsequent sed command to uncomment lines in the pacman.conf file, but it isn't working. Specifically, I want to uncomment these two lines:
YC="\033[1;33m"
RC="\033[0m"

RCH() {
    echo -e "${YC}    $*${RC}"
    arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "$*" | sed 's/^/    /'
}

RCH sed '/^#\[multilib\]/s/^#//n;/^#Include/s/^#//' /etc/pacman.conf

#[multilib]
#Include ...

Here is what I need:

Search for a line starting with #[multilib]. If found, uncomment it.
Move to the next line and search for a line starting with #Include. If found, uncomment it. Then stop, no further searching or modifications.

Update:
I thank you all very much for guiding me in the right direction. I modified the script like this, and so far, everything works except space key to continue.
WAIT() {
    echo -e "Press ${GC}SPACE${RC} to continue or ${GC}ESC${RC} to exit .."
    while true; do        
        read -n 1 -s key
        if [[ $key == " " ]]; then
            break
        elif [[ $key == $'\e' ]]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done
}
RUN() {
    echo -e "${YC}    $*${RC}"
    WAIT
    /bin/bash -c "$@" | sed 's/^/      /'
}
RUN "sed -i '/^#\[multilib\]/{s/^#//;n;/^#Include/s/^#//}' /etc/pacman.conf"
RUN "echo LANG=${LOCALE} > /etc/locale.conf"
RUN "cat <<EOL > /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
EOL"


What is the generic idea/target? For me this is like XY problem.

set -x sounds like what you want. It prints all commands the shell executes, with the variables etc. expanded. Put the set -x at the top of the script (or set -o xtrace if you like the more verbose variant)

You say it isn't working, can you explain how it isn't working? What were you expecting to  happen and what actually happens?

@RomeoNinov Generally, I want every command to be displayed before its execution. Later, I would add options to proceed or skip the command, but I'm not sure if my function is written correctly or if it just creates additional problems.

@Suggorath That is an important aspect of the problem; please edit the question to include it.

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for some relevant information on the kinds of issues you'll need to consider.

Not a complete answer, but note that this...
/bin/bash -c "$*"

...will not do what you want. Let's simplify your RCH function to:
RCH() {
  /bin/bash -c "$*"
}

Consider the behavior if we do something like this:
RCH sed 's/hello world/goodnight moon' somefile.txt

You get:
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

And that's because you're discarding the tokenization of the original command. Instead of passing two arguments to sed (s/hello world/goodnight moon/ and somefile.txt), you're effectively running the command without quotes:
sed s/hello world/goodnight moon/ somefile.txt

That's four arguments (s/hello, world/goodnight, moon/, somefile.txt), and that's an invalid command. This is a contrived example, of course, but it's very easy to run into situations where this is a real problem.
You can get the appropriate behavior if you instead write:
RCH() {
  bash -c '"$@"' -- "$@"
}

(The -- is just a placeholder for $0 so that the first argument to RCH becomes $1 in the subshell.)
This will preserve the original tokenization of the command line:
$ echo hello world > somefile.txt
$ RCH sed 's/hello world/goodnight moon/' somefile.txt
goodnight moon


-s conflicts with -c. -s is to take the code from stdin while allowing extra arguments, while -c is to take the code as the next argument instead (and in any case accepting extra arguments). I won't used -- for $0. The value of $0 is also used in error messages for instance, so having -- there would be confusing. I'd do /bin/sh -c 'exec "$@"' sh "$@" or just "$@", (or /usr/bin/env "$@" if the reason for using sh/bash is that arch-chroot can't do $PATH lookup of commands).

Yeah, not sure what I was thinking there. Good catch!

My suggestion is to print/echo all your command to the screen.  Read them and check that they are correct, then: re-run the command but pipe it to a shell.
(./cmds.sh | /bin/sh)
Better yet, redirect to a file and then execute the file; that way, if everything goes kablooie, at least the cause will be in the file.
...Because, running commands like that from the innards of a shell-program is disaster.
